# What are the parameters to consider while selecting MOSFET or IGBT for Inverter and SMPS Design

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, inverter, igbt

I'm working on a project to design Buck Converter with following Criteria
Vin: 4.5-60V
Vout:8-15V
Iout:6-12Amps

Comment: A lot. Download a couple of data sheets. Everything specified in there is specified for the reason that someone needs that info for their application. So, your question is too broad.

Comment: As Marcus notes, there are a lot; more than that, the details are different *for every design*. Try asking about a specific design and why the choices you see were made and you may get a thorough answer.

Comment: Its difficult to be specific without more details.  I'd look at the application notes for the control IC you want to use. These often give clues on what your switching devices need to be capable of.

Comment: The parameters to consider are the ones given in the datasheet. This is rather a broad question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree completely with Marcus's comment, however one important thing to consider is that as the rated voltage goes up, MOSFET on resistance increases very quickly.

An IGBT has a saturation voltage that increases only slowly with collector current.

So if your average device current results in a greater drop across the MOSFET RDSon than the IGBT sat voltage, the IGBT looks better from a conduction loss perspective.  This is usually the case for say 600V and higher bus voltages.

Of course IGBTs switch slower, especially on turn-off (stored charge) so switching losses can be worse if you have to switch at higher frequencies.

Then there's everything else as Marcus pointed out.....

Answer (score 1):

The electrical parameters to consider when choosing a MOSFET are a lot!

For SMPS applications the parasitic parameters of a MOSFET are critical, these determine your transition time, your on- resistance, ringing (overshoot when switching) and back-gate breakdown that all relate to effeciency of your SMPS.
[This image](https://engineering.phys.msu.ru/images/bivos/4.jpg) depicts most of the relevant paracitics for a MOSFET.

For a power switch you typically want:

1. Very low on resistance (That comes from choosing a wide and short channel MOSFET)
2. Low input capacitance (expacially the Miller capacitance)
3. Low paracitic inductance to drain and source to minimise voltage spikes during switching (Think in terms of physically short connections to your other components)
4. High bake-gate breakdown (high enough to handle whatever voltage spikes your paracitic inductance gives you)

For a gate driver (supposing that's what you mean by inverter) you typically want:

1. Low input capacitance for fast switching
2. High drive strength (That is again given by choosing a wide and short channel device. Rule of thumb is to use a MOSFET with 1/3 of the width "W" and 1/3 of the length "L" that your respective power MOSFET has

There is a lot more to this subject than what I've mentioned, but it might be a good place to start. Hope it helps.

Comment: "RoT is to use a mosfet with 1/3 of the width "W" and 1/3 of the length "L" that your respective power MOSFET has". I have never seen any of this data available. Can you elborate what you mean by this? Thanks